# VBScript that runs a macro in excel throws an error

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I have a vbscript that opens an excel workbook and runs a particular macro inside at a particular time on a particular day. Here it is

```
Option Explicit

Dim xlApp, xlBook

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = False

While not (Month(Now()) = 11 and Day(Now()) = 17 and Hour(Now()) = 9 and Minute(Now()) = 1)
Wend

Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\Property by Peril.xlsm")
xlApp.Application.Run "'Property by Peril.xlsm'!Main"

Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing

WScript.Echo "Finished."
WScript.Quit
```

It runs fine up to and including the opening of the workbook and the running of the macro. However, immediately after the macro runs, I get an error

```
Microsoft VBScript runtim error: Unknown runtime error   (on line 16)
```

and the rest of the script does not get executed.

Any thoughts/help?

Comment: Have you tried running the macro from Excel directly? It may not be your VBScript failing but the macro itself..?

Comment: Yes, @vba4all , good thinking. But I did run it directly and it works just fine on its own.

Comment: have you tried removing the workbook name? it's not necessary just leave the macro name (`.Run "Main"`)? Also which one is `line 16`?

Comment: I just tried your suggestion, @vba4all , but with the same result. It opens the workbook and runs the macro, but then stops there. Line 16 is the `.Run` line, which is odd because that line runs fine. It's just the ones after that don't run and the error is triggered.

Comment: hm.. maybe you're missing the `xlApp.close` line or something that will close the file before setting references to `Nothing`? can you share the code from `Main`?

Comment: The code in Main closes the workbook after it's all done, so I thought there'd be no need to close it in the VBScript. Do you think that is where the problem is?

Comment: Remove/comment the statement that closes the workbook in the macro, and add a line `xlBook.Close False` after the `.Run` statement.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, that was exactly it! If you like, draw it up as a solution and I'd happily reward your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the statement to close the workbook from the macro and adding it to the VBScript. Also, don't forget to quit the application object, otherwise your hidden Excel instance will keep lingering in memory, because it's not automatically discarded when the script terminates.

```
...
xlApp.Application.Run "'Property by Peril.xlsm'!Main"

xlBook.Close False
xlApp.Quit

Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
...
```

The parameter `False` will prevent changes to the workbook from being saved. Change it to `True` if you want changes to be automatically saved.

Answer (score 1):

The following code ran successfully on my system.

```
Option Explicit

Dim xlApp, xlBook

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = False

Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\Property by Peril.xlsm")
xlApp.Application.Run "Main"

xlBook.Close False
Set xlBook = Nothing
xlApp.Quit
Set xlApp = Nothing

WScript.Echo "Finished."
WScript.Quit
```